# How to make dice not overlap when being thrown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, css

I'm making a mobile app, and a part of it is being able to throw dice.
I'm working with Ionic as mobile framework and using angular and jquery to make the dice roll. The problem is when i roll multiple dice, that these dice can appear on the same spot, so basicly overlap eachother. I tried working with the jquery offset() and position() and then saying the left value of the dice can never be the same, that way the dice will always appear in another 'column'.
but somehow this didn't work because it registered the position before rolling, and not after rolling.

Here is my code:

dice.html

```
<ion-view view-title="dice" id="dice">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
        <ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-content id="dice" scroll="true">

             <button class="btn orange" id="addDie1" type="button"><span>Add second die</span></button>
             <button class="btn red" id="addDie2" type="button"><span>Add third die</span></button>    
        <section id="roll-wrap">
<div id="die" style="transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);">
    <div class="sf f1">1</div>
    <div class="sf f2">2</div>
    <div class="sf f3">3</div>
    <div class="sf f4">4</div>
    <div class="sf f5">5</div>
    <div class="sf f6">6</div>
</div>
<div id="die2" style="transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(90deg);">
    <div class="sf f1">1</div>
    <div class="sf f2">2</div>
    <div class="sf f3">3</div>
    <div class="sf f4">4</div>
    <div class="sf f5">5</div>
    <div class="sf f6">6</div>
</div>
<div id="die3" style="transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(180deg);">
    <div class="sf f1">1</div>
    <div class="sf f2">2</div>
    <div class="sf f3">3</div>
    <div class="sf f4">4</div>
    <div class="sf f5">5</div>
    <div class="sf f6">6</div>
</div>
</section>
<button class="btn orange" id="play" type="button"><span>Roll it</span></button>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

controllers.js

```
.controller('DiceCtrl', function($scope) {

     (function($, self){
      if(!$ || !self) {
      return;
      }
      for(var i=0; i<self.properties.length; i++) {
      var property = self.properties[i],
      camelCased = StyleFix.camelCase(property),
      PrefixCamelCased = self.prefixProperty(property, true);
      $.cssProps[camelCased] = PrefixCamelCased;
      }
      })(window.jQuery, window.PrefixFree);

    //Actual code for Play Action , still buggy for 2 dice stacking on top of eachother
    $(function(){

    $("#addDie1").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#die2").css("display","block");
    });
    $("#addDie2").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#die3").css("display","block");
    });
    $()
    var x=[0,90,180,270];
    $("#play").click(function(e){
       var position = $(".sf").offset();
      var position2 = $("#die2 .sf").offset();
      var position3 = $("#die3 .sf").offset();
      console.log(position);
      console.log(position2);
      console.log(position3);
      e.preventDefault();
      do {
        var rand1=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
        var rand2=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
        var rand3=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
        var rand4=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
        var rand5=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
        var rand6=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
      } while((x[rand1] == x[rand3] && x[rand2] == x[rand4]) || (x[rand1] == x[rand5] && x[rand2] == x[rand6]) || (x[rand3] == x[rand5] && x[rand4] == x[rand6]))

        console.log(x[rand1] + "\n" + x[rand2] + "\n" + x[rand3] + "\n" + x[rand4] + "\n" + x[rand5] + "\n" + x[rand6] + "\n")
        $("#die").css("transform","rotateX("+x[rand1]+"deg) rotateY("+x[rand2]+"deg)");
        $("#die2").css("transform","rotateX("+x[rand3]+"deg) rotateY("+x[rand4]+"deg)"); 
        $("#die3").css("transform","rotateX("+x[rand5]+"deg) rotateY("+x[rand6]+"deg)");    


      });
    });
})
```

style.css

```
#dice {
    background: url("../img/dice_bg.jpg") no-repeat;  
    background-position: center; 
    background-size: cover;
}
#roll-wrap {
perspective: 800;
perspective-origin: 50% 200px;
}
#addDie1, #addDie2{
width: 50%;
}
#addDie2 {
    float:right;
}
#play {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-width: 0;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  color: #ecf0f1; 
  transition: background-color .3s;
}
.btn > * {
  position: relative;
}

.btn span {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
}

.btn.orange {
  background-color: #e67e22;
}

.btn.orange:hover, .btn.orange:focus {
  background-color: #d35400;
}

.btn.red {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.btn.red:hover, .btn.red:focus {
  background-color: #c0392b;
}

#die {
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
  height: 400px;
  width: 90%;
  transition: transform 1.5s linear;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#die2 {
  position: relative;
  margin: -400px auto 0;
  height: 400px;
  width: 90%;
  transition: transform 1.5s linear;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;

}
#die3 {
  position: relative;
  margin: -400px auto 0;
  height: 400px;
  width: 90%;
  transition: transform 1.5s linear;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;

}
.sf {
  position: absolute;
  height: 62px;
  width: 62px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color:white;;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;

}
/* TranslateZ = hoever elk vlak vaneen moet staan. rotateX waar het moet staan */
#die .f1, #die2 .f1, #die3 .f1  {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(30px);
}
#die .f2, #die2 .f2, #die3 .f2  {
  transform: translateZ(30px);
}
#die .f3, #die2 .f3, #die3 .f1 {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(30px);
}
#die .f4, #die2 .f4, #die3 .f4 {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(30px);
}
#die .f5, #die2 .f5, #die3 .f5 {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(30px);
}
#die .f6, #die2 .f6, #die3 .f6 {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotate(180deg) translateZ(30px);
}
```